# Spring MVC restful path

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller

Hi I have created a Spring MVC Application, I have Controller called Estimation with two methods.

I can access the **home method** of this controller by going to this url **www.wesite.com/xyz/estimation**

but I try to access **homeById** method by going to this url **www.wesite.com/xyz/estimation/1** 
I get a 404 error, The requested resource is not available.

can any body please shed some light on it.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/estimation")
public class EstimationController {

 @RequestMapping("")
 public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) {

   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("productEstimate");
   return mv; 

    }

   @RequestMapping(value="/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homeById(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable int productId) {

     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("productEstimate"); 

     return mv;
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml,
        WEB-INF/classes/spring/hibernateContext.xml
    </param-value>    </context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>projectName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>projectName</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/estimation/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
         <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/views/" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
         <property name="layoutUrl" value="layout.vm"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You can get that error both if the mapping is not matched or if the view cannot be rendered (but I see you are using the same view for both requests, so if the first works, so should the second). See if you have an error like `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI`

Answer (score 2):

When referring the path variable use something like this

```
 @PathVariable("productId") int productId
```

This enclosed variable name is same as the variable name in the request mapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```